# How to extract multiple float values from a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to extract numeric values from a string inside a pandas DataFrame.

Let's say the DataFrame cell is as follows (stored as a string):

```
[1.234,2.345]
```

I can get the first value with the following:

```
print(df['column_name'].str.extract('(\d+.\d+)',).astype('float'))
```

Output:

```
1.234
```

Now my thoughts to find both values was to do the following:

```
print(df['column_name'].str.extract('(\d+.\d+),(\d+.\d+)',).astype('float'))
```

but the output is then as follows:

```
NaN NaN
```

Expected output:

```
1.234 2.345
```

Comment: Looks like there is a space after your comma there.  `df['column_name'].str.extract('(\d+.\d+)\,\s(\d+.\d+)',)`

Comment: @Chris df['column_name'].str.extract('(\d+.\d+)\,\s(\d+.\d+)',) still results in NaN Nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just `pd.eval`:

```
>>> df['Float'] = pd.eval(df['String'])
>>> df
           String           Float
0  [1.234, 2.345]  [1.234, 2.345]
1  [1.234, 2.345]  [1.234, 2.345]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a regex to extract floats, you can use `str.findall`:

```
>>> df['column_name'].str.findall(r'(-?\d+\.?\d+)').str.join(' ')
0    1.234 2.345
Name: String, dtype: object
```

---

**Old answer**:
Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame({'String': ['[1.234, 2.345]']})

df['Float'] = df['String'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
           String           Float
0  [1.234, 2.345]  [1.234, 2.345]

>>> type(df.at[0, 'String'][0])
str

>>> type(df.at[0, 'Float'][0])
float
```

Comment: @Hellothere. Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.str.split](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html?highlight=split#pandas.Series.str.split), setting `n=2`. If you want to expand the DataFrame you must set `expand=True`.
So the result might look like:

```
your_dataframe['your_column_name'].str.split(",", n=2, expand=True).astype(float)
```